# This code takes 30 seconds to run, I'm clearly doing something wrong

Tags: c#

This code takes a while to perform, even though all I need it to do is get a string of text off a website. I have this at this point

```
private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string word = "1.5";

        try
        {
            var url = "http://chipperyman573.com/rtf/textbot.html";
            var client = new WebClient();
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string downloadedString;
                while ((downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (downloadedString == word)
                    {
                        //The stuff happens if there's no update
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //The stuff that happens if there is an update
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //The stuff that happens if it can't connect to the webpage
        }
    }
```

This takes roughly 30 seconds to happen, and it should be super fast. The page only has text on it.

Comment: Put 'downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()' outside the 'while' and write the loop like:while ((downloadedString) != null). It probably wont make a difference, but theres no need to copy reader.ReadLine() every time the while loops.

Comment: The `client.OpenRead(url)` takes 1 to 4 seconds here. About the same that it take for me to reload the page manually. Seems fine.

Comment: I don't know, it takes around 30 seconds in the program but only 1-3 to load it in chrome.

Comment: When you step through it with the debugger, where does it spend its time?

Comment: @Nilzone- if the read occurs outside the loop, the code will process the same data forever.

Comment: using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))

Comment: You might try commenting out various sections of the code to find out which one causes the bottleneck.  Start by commenting out everything inside the loop, then replace one branch of the if, and so on.

Comment: I think your code is OK, on my machine it ran in under 1 second. I think you should check your IE settings, or try to reach this URL with Internet Explorer, since WebClient is using IE's proxy settings.

Comment: Oh, it uses IE? That explains it.

Comment: Have you tried out in IE?

Comment: Yes, I was kidding when I left the comment. M.T.Bennet posted some other code that seems to work.

Comment: What are you doing in the "stuff that happens" if there is or isn't an update? The download should be roughly the same as if you downloaded from a browser. That's probably where you're spending all your time.

Comment: You should debug the code before posting your question, so we do not have to play the debugging game for you. If you do not know how to use the debugger, then say that.

Comment: I know how to, I did it and posted my response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried just using a HttpWebRequest object? The WebClient is a higher level wrapper that maybe taking liberties that you don't need.
Just used this code and it took just over a second to run..

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://chipperyman573.com/rtf/textbot.html");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```